# C# Process.Start can't find exe (ssh-keygen)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

This is failing with "the system cannot find the file specified."

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   string command = @"C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh-keygen.exe";
   Process.Start(command, "");'
}
```

If I cut and paste the path to the "Developer PowerShell" it does run from there.
If I cut and paste the path to an admin or non-admin cmd prompt or powershell window it works.
But the above code fails whether I compile and run it outside of vs or via the debugger.
If I sub in string `string command = @"C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe"` that works.
If cut and paste the code to a different VS on a different machine it works.
The failing VS is 2019 and the succeeding is 2022 but can't see how that would impact things.
Any idea what's going on?

Comment: What happens if you execute the compiled console .exe as an administrator?

Comment: It failed from admin or non-admin prompts. Looks like it was the file system redirector issue Tu deschizi eu inchid mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is most likely due to the [File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector).

Try the following:

```
string command = string.Empty;

//environment variable windir has the same value as SystemRoot
//use 'Sysnative' to access 64-bit files (in System32) if program is running as 32-bit process
//use 'SysWow64' to access 32-bit files on 64-bit OS


if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem && !Environment.Is64BitProcess)
{
    command = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir"), "Sysnative", "OpenSSH", "ssh-keygen.exe");
}
else
{
    command = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir"),"OpenSSH", "ssh-keygen.exe");
}
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you! Note that your code snip above has 'Sysnative' for both paths so you may want to tweak that for future readers.